# How to filter Meteor database query results?

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, meteor

I'm having so much trouble finding an elegant way of filtering by mongodb query results against an array of objects I dont want.

I get an array of objects:

```
var articles = Tips.find().fetch();
```

And I have a few articles that have already been selected and should be returned

```
var selected = [{Object}, {Object}];
```

I find it hard to believe that theres no built in function such as:

```
articles.remove(selected);
```

But there isn't, and given the amount we're working with MongoDb in Meteor, I figured someone has already found some good helper functions for doing this and other similar functionality

Thanks

Comment: I'm a little unsure about what you are asking for. Do you want `articles` to contain a list of all articles which do **not** include those in `selected`? If so, is `selected` available at the time you run the query for `articles`?

Comment: Yes. Is there a way to do something like find({$except:selected})?

Comment: hmm. $nin seems to do what I want, but it doesnt seem to be implemented with Meteor... http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you suggested in your comment, I believe `$nin` is what you want (yes, it's available in meteor). For example:

```
var selectedIds = _.pluck(selected, _id);
var articles = Tips.find({_id: {$nin: selectedIds}});
```

This is also nice if you are running it on the client because you don't have to call `fetch` prior to rendering.

Comment: That's it. totally works. I'm still interested in knowing why my removeObjs function doesnt work though...

Answer (score 2):

So I found a reasonable solution, but its incomplete:

```
Array.prototype.removeObjWithValue = function(name, value){
    var array = $.map(this, function(v,i){
        return v[name] === value ? null : v;
    });
    this.length = 0; //clear original array
    this.push.apply(this, array); //push all elements except the one we want to delete
}

Array.prototype.removeObj = function(obj){
    var array = $.map(this, function(v,i){
        return v["_id"] === obj["_id"] ? null : v;
    });
    this.length = 0; //clear original array
    this.push.apply(this, array); //push all elements except the one we want to delete
}
```

The problem I am still running into is that this doesnt work and keep returning []

```
Array.prototype.removeObjs = function(objs){
    var array = this;
    console.log(array);
    $.each(objs, function (i,v) {
        array.removeObj(v);
        console.log(array);
    })
    console.log(array);
    this.length = 0; //clear original array
    this.push.apply(this, array); //push all elements except the ones we want to delete
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using underscore.js (present by default in Meteor), try

```
_.difference(articles, [{Object}, {Object}]);
```

Source: http://underscorejs.org/#difference